# c# PowerPoint Slide interop and office dll registry error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, registry, powerpoint

I am in need of read a PPT/X PowerPoint File in C# code and display that in web form as image.

I did it using in VS 2013 C# .NET 4.0 and using dlls, Microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.dll and Office.DLL.

It is working perfectly fine when running on local machine and working in local machine.

When I publish it on Azure Web Server or in Shared Server IIS,

I am ending up with

*

> Error occurred: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with
>   CLSID {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} failed due to the
>   following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

*

I copied both DLLs into BIN folder.

Still no use.

Any idea how can i resolve this!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just try enabling the  fusion logs, it may be the case that your library is not signed and due to that your are getting this exception. Try disabling the strong name validation using `sn -Vr`